# mongoid: how reset model changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I see, that mongoid has reset filed method:

```
person = Person.first
person.name = "Alan Garner"

# Reset the changed name back to the original
person.reset_name!
```

But I have many fields in my model, and in at any given point, some it fields can become invalid.
1. How can I reset invalid fields in the model?
2. How can I reset all model to the initial state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply try:

```
 person = Person.first

 #for invalid
 person.errors.each do |field, message|
   method_name = "reset_#{field}!"
   person.send(method_name)
 end

 #for all
 person.attributes.each do |field, value|
   method_name = "reset_#{field}!"
   person.send(method_name)
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just do this to reset all fields:

```
 person.reload
```

It's simpler but hits database.